Despite loading core-js & regenerator-runtime I still can't get async/await to work for my JavaScript with WebPack
An async/await call doesn't work.  I loaded core-js and regenerator-runtime to fix that but it still isn't working.  I'm guessing it's a matter of the proper components.  That's why I posted my package.json and webpack.config.js files below.
const getPuzzle = async (wordCount) => {
    const response = await fetch(`//puzzle.mead.io/puzzle?wordCount=${wordCount}`, {
        mode: 'no-cors'
    })
    if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = await response.json()
        return data.puzzle
    } else {
        throw new Error('Unable to get puzzle')
    }
}

the error
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
Unable to get puzzle
    at _callee$ (http://localhost:8080/scripts/bundle.js:392:17)
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:8080/scripts/bundle.js:367:1062)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/scripts/bundle.js:367:3008)
    at Generator.next (http://localhost:8080/scripts/bundle.js:367:1699)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:8080/scripts/bundle.js:368:70)
    at _next (http://localhost:8080/scripts/bundle.js:369:163)

package.json:
{
  "name": "boilerplate2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "input.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "webpack serve --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack serve --open --mode development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.25.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.4",
    "babel-loader": "^9.2.1",
    "core-js": "^3.38.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.14.1",
    "webpack": "^5.94.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.1.0"
  }
}

webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: ['core-js/stable', 'regenerator-runtime/runtime', './src/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
        },
        port: 8080,
        devMiddleware: {
            publicPath: "//localhost:8080/scripts/"
        }
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
}

Any help is appreciated!

you're using mode: "no-cors" then expecting to read the result - that's the issue - nothing to do with core-js/regenerator-runtime which would only be needed for very old browsers - read what mode:"no-cors" means, then get rid of it from your code

Thanks for suggestion.  Still not working.  I get:
Access to fetch at 'http://puzzle.mead.io/puzzle?wordCount=2' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.---
GET http://puzzle.mead.io/puzzle?wordCount=2 net::ERR_FAILED---
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch---
Any idea what's behind this?

Yes, this is a CORS issue. I could've guessed you used mode: "no-cors" in an attempt to overcome CORS issues, but CORS is always controlled by the server. i.e.,  the site puzzle.mead.io does not allow cross origin requests from browsers - you'll need to proxy the request through a server you control

The problem was not with Webpack or the components I chose.  The problem was with the JavaScript in the async request:
const getPuzzle = async (wordCount) => {
    const response = await fetch(`//puzzle.mead.io/puzzle?wordCount=${wordCount}`, {
        mode: 'no-cors'
    })

mode: 'no-cors' should not have been there.  Also, "https:" should have been in front of //puzzle... in the URL call.  Once these 2 issues were fixed, everything was fine.
